# Difference between below mentioned Admob Ads initialization method?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am trying to find out the correct syntax of Admob Ads initialization method in unity because when I looked for it I found two methods 
1. MobileAds.Initialize(APP_ID);
and
2. MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
So don't know that if I have to use the 2nd method then app id will be mentioned in brackets or not???

```
MobileAds.Initialize(APP_ID);
OR
MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
```